# Как найти линейно зависимые векторы в матрице?

Tags: python, numpy

Нужно найти линейно зависимые векторы в матрице произвольного размера. В примере такими векторами есть второй и четвертый.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    ])
```

Пробовал банальным перебором, но получилось очень громоздко и криво, поэтому даже не стал дописывать. Надеюсь, есть способ проще.
Еще пытался использовать np.linalg.eig, но не могу разобраться как ее правильно использовать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28816627/7485582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-то пригодится, решил проблему таким образом:

```
from itertools import combinations
from numpy import sum as npsum

def combs(matr):
    arr = []
    for k in range(2, len(matr) + 1):
        rows = combinations(matr,k)
        indices = list(combinations(range(len(matr)), k))
        for i, j in enumerate(rows):
            if sum(npsum(j, axis=0) % 2) == 0: 
                arr.append(indices[i])
    return arr
```

Answer (score 2):

По идее, надо смотреть матрицу корреляции, которую даёт `np.corrcoef`, но как её правильно интерпретировать я сходу не соображу. Хотя и вижу единички не на диагонали:

```
print(np.corrcoef(matrix))
```

Вывод:

```
[[ 1.          0.31622777 -0.25        0.31622777]
 [ 0.31622777  1.         -0.31622777  1.        ]
 [-0.25       -0.31622777  1.         -0.31622777]
 [ 0.31622777  1.         -0.31622777  1.        ]]
```

Подумал ещё, сочинил вот такого монстра:

```
print(np.nonzero(np.isclose(np.abs(np.corrcoef(matrix) - np.eye(matrix.shape[0])), 1.)))
```

Пошагово:

- `corrcoef` - берём матрицу корреляции
- вычитаем `eye` - убираем единицы с диагонали (корреляция векторов с самими собой нас не интересует)
- `abs` - берём абсолютное значение коэффициентов корреляции (отрицательная корреляция - тоже корреляция)
- `isclose` - проверяем на близость получившихся коэффициентов к 1 (точное равенство может не всегда соблюдаться для чисел с плавающей точкой)
- `nonzero` - получаем индексы найденных линейно коррелирующих векторов

На выходе:

```
(array([1, 3]), array([3, 1]))
```

Интерпретировать можно так (учитывая, что индексация в Питоне идёт с 0, т.е. в вашем случае имеем векторы под индексом 0, 1, 2, 3): вектор 1 линейно коррелирует с вектором 3; и наоборот: вектор 3 линейно коррелирует с вектором 1.

Comment: спасибо большое! это работает, пускай и не для всех случаев (иногда пропускает линейные векторы и ищет просто одинаковые)

Comment: @TedMosby Обновил подсчёт. Теперь правильно ищет и для отрицательной корреляции, и не требует корреляции ровно 1.0, что для чисел с плавающей точкой может не всегда срабатывать

Comment: @TedMosby А можете привести примеры, когда не срабатывает? Что там в матрице корреляции, интересно.

Comment: Возможно причина в том, что оно работает только на два вектора? А в матрице могут больше двух векторов быть зависимыми. Сейчас наведу пример в отдельном посте

Comment: У меня программа генерирует эту матрицу в цикле, с каждой итерацией матрица увеличивается по определенным формулам. Суть в том, что когда получается вот такая матрица: matrix = np.array([
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
    ])

Comment: То оно не замечает линейности, хотя здесь векторы с индексами 2, 4, 6, 8 все вместе зависимы между собой

Comment: Да, под такую корреляцию этот вариант не заточен, надо ещё думать :)